Apache SSL crash after some time, doesn't serve the SSL cert
I'm currently experiencing a weird issue with Apache 2.4, after some time (like 1 day), my apache doesn't serve the SSL certificate that is installed in the virtualhost. I have to restart apache in order to make it serve the SSL certificate again.
This is my current virtualhost configuration (I have to hide the server domain) :
<VirtualHost XXX:80>
    ServerName XXX
    Redirect permanent / https://XXX/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost XXX:443>
    DocumentRoot "/home/project/staging/dashboard/build"
    ServerName XXX

    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" vhost_combined
    LogFormat "%v %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" vhost_common

    <Directory "/home/project/staging/dashboard/build">
        Options -Indexes
        Require all granted
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.\.\/
        RewriteRule ^ - [F]
    </Directory>

    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/XXX/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/XXX/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>

There's no errors at all when I restart apache.
And no relevant errors either in apache logs..
I'm adding the logs that's being written when I restart apache:
[Sun Oct 06 09:35:04.051573 2024] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 650835:tid 650835] AH00163: Apache/2.4.62 (Debian) OpenSSL/1.1.1w configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Oct 06 09:35:04.051591 2024] [core:notice] [pid 650835:tid 650835] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Oct 06 09:35:18.304163 2024] [authz_core:error] [pid 682856:tid 682856] [client 139.59.132.8:43442] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/project/staging/dashboard/build/server-status
[Sun Oct 06 09:35:32.594377 2024] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 650835:tid 650835] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'openssl' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20220829/openssl (/usr/lib/php/20220829/openssl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20220829/openssl.so (/usr/lib/php/20220829/openssl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'xsl' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20220829/xsl (/usr/lib/php/20220829/xsl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20220829/xsl.so (/usr/lib/php/20220829/xsl.so: undefined symbol: dom_node_class_entry)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "curl" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "exif" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "fileinfo" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "ftp" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "gd" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "gettext" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "intl" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "mbstring" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "mysqli" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "pdo_mysql" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "soap" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "zip" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[Sun Oct 06 09:35:32.932134 2024] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 650835:tid 650835] AH00163: Apache/2.4.62 (Debian) OpenSSL/1.1.1w configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Oct 06 09:35:32.932155 2024] [core:notice] [pid 650835:tid 650835] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

SOLVED : I had to create a multi-domain/subdomains SSL certificate. Apache was randomly serving multiple SSL certificates, I don't know why though.

There is a CATALOG of issues in the config and logs you posted. I would strongly recommend you wipe this machine and start again following normal practices.

SOLVED : I had to create a multi-domain/subdomains SSL certificate. Apache was randomly serving multiple SSL certificates
